# Add all the rows of a column and store in another column

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using this query and the result of it is as:

```
SELECT     
  t.TestId,
  t.Days,
  t.FullName  
  [Date] = Convert(date,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn))),
  CheckIn = CONVERT(CHAR(5), t.CheckIn, 108),
  CheckOut = CONVERT(CHAR(5), t.CheckOut, 108),
  [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM (
  SELECT 
    FullName = Users.FullName,
    TestId = t.TestId,
    Days = t.Days,
    t.UserId_Fk,
    CheckIn = t.CheckInTime,
    CheckOut = r.CheckInTime,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserId_Fk, r.CheckInTime ORDER BY 1/0)
FROM UserTime t 
INNER JOIN Users
ON t.UserId_Fk=Users.UserId
    OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM UserTime t2
      WHERE 
        t2.CheckInTime > t.CheckInTime
        AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckInTime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.CheckInTime))
        AND t2.LoginStatus = 'O'
      ORDER BY t2.CheckInTime
) r
WHERE t.LoginStatus = 'I' 
) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```

Result:

```
TestId Days   FullName      Date   CheckIn CheckOut  Hours
11  Wednesday   Antonio 2014-05-14  10:19   10:20   0.02
13  Wednesday   Antonio 2014-05-14  10:19   10:20   0.02
14  Wednesday    Tim    2014-05-14  10:20   10:21   0.02
```

Table Structure:

Table UserTime:

```
TestId   int(pk)    
UserId_Fk    int    
Days     nvarchar(50)
Date         date
CheckInTime  datetime
LoginStatus  char(1)
```

Table Users:

```
UserId    int(Pk)   
FullName  varchar(50)
```

I want a column named **TotalHours** which Adds All the fields of Hours Column and Display the value.

Somewhat like this:

```
TestId Days     FullName   Date   CheckIn CheckOut Hours  TotalHours
 11 Wednesday   Antonio 2014-05-14  10:19   10:20   0.02    0.04
 11 Wednesday   Antonio 2014-05-14  10:19   10:20   0.02
 13 Wednesday    Tim    2014-05-14  10:20   10:21   0.02
```

Comment: Once or for every row?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. According to Users. So Add Hours column according to UserId_Fk.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two queries in the left query sum the total hours and in the right select the required column then join the queries.

```
 select * from
   (SELECT testid,sum(Hours) as total from(
       SELECT     
       t.TestId,
       t.FullName  ,
       [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))

      FROM (
            SELECT 
            FullName = Users.FullName,
            TestId = t.TestId,
            Days = t.Days,
            t.UserId_Fk,
            CheckIn = t.CheckInTime,
            CheckOut = r.CheckInTime,
            RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserId_Fk, r.CheckInTime ORDER  BY 1/0)
            FROM UserTime t 
            INNER JOIN Users
            ON t.UserId_Fk=Users.UserId
            OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM UserTime t2
            WHERE 
            t2.CheckInTime > t.CheckInTime
            AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckInTime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.CheckInTime))
       AND t2.LoginStatus = 'O'
  ORDER BY t2.CheckInTime
  ) r
   WHERE t.LoginStatus = 'I' 
  ) t
    WHERE t.RowNum = 1
  )s
  group by s.FullName,testid)O


  INNER JOIN 

  (
   SELECT     
   t.TestId,
   t.Days,
   t.FullName  ,
   [Date] = Convert(date,DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckIn))),
   CheckIn = CONVERT(CHAR(5), t.CheckIn, 108),
   CheckOut = CONVERT(CHAR(5), t.CheckOut, 108),
   [Hours] = CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.CheckIn, t.CheckOut) / 60. AS DECIMAL(10,2))

   FROM (
      SELECT 
      FullName = Users.FullName,
      TestId = t.TestId,
      Days = t.Days,
      t.UserId_Fk,
      CheckIn = t.CheckInTime,
      CheckOut = r.CheckInTime,
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.UserId_Fk, r.CheckInTime ORDER BY 1/0)
      FROM UserTime t 
      INNER JOIN Users
      ON t.UserId_Fk=Users.UserId
      OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM UserTime t2
  WHERE 
    t2.CheckInTime > t.CheckInTime
    AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t.CheckInTime)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, t2.CheckInTime))
    AND t2.LoginStatus = 'O'
  ORDER BY t2.CheckInTime
 ) r
WHERE t.LoginStatus = 'I' 
 ) t
WHERE t.RowNum = 1
)I
on i.testid=o.testid
```